# Facebook Slide menu-slide to right in android?

Tags: android, facebook, user-interface

I used [maddeye](https://github.com/maddeye/android-sidemenu) slide menu library to implement a Facebook like slide bar.  It works fine, sliding from right to left.

Now what I want is to slide from left to right as the new Facebook app in Android.

What modification should I use to make this change? Does anyone know how to slide both sides as the new Facebook app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would try the android-menudrawer project at https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer which just hit 1.0.0 thanks to Jake Wharton.

I tried it out yesterday and it looks like it fits your needs.

If you build and install the sample APK, you'll see an example called "Right menu" which is what I think you're looking for.  The other examples are variations of the normal sliding menu.

Here are screenshots of this sample APK (MenuDrawerSamples) in action.  The first screenshot shows the Right Menu example with the menu drawer closed.  Tap on the overflow menu item in the upper right corner and then it reveals the menu, as shown in the second screenshot.  You could trigger it instead from another action bar button or other button if desired.

[image: Right Menu - Closed]
[image: Right Menu - Open]

Comment: it it slide left means when i click the right  above button the  above view slide to left

Comment: hey louielouie i try to implemented this but full fo error and also in the librray folder resource in empty if u have the working code please share

Comment: I added screenshots of this in action.  Once you clone the https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer project, take a look at the RightMenuSample.java file which will give you the working code that you need.

Comment: thank u bro at lat i got the solution from you answer i dont know why this quetion closed  any way friends follow this answer it works thank you louielouies for sharing this data:)

Comment: louielouie today i implemented this answer sucessfully in my project and worked 100% now i can slide my view in two sides thanks a lot

Comment: Hi I implemented this project after that my layout doesnot scroll neither main nor drawer listview plz suggest me